# Nestjs CRUD restrict usage for specific actions

Tags: nestjs

At the moment to implement [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud) is very easy to create a CRUD, but what happens if I want to omit the "Delete" ?

**User service**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService extends TypeOrmCrudService<UserService>{
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) repo) {
    super(repo)
  }
}
```

**Usercontroller**

```
@Crud({
    model: {
      type: User
    }
  })
  
  @Controller('todo')
  export class UserController implements CrudController<UserService> {
    constructor(public service: UserService) {}
  }
```

It's very simple, with that I have my CRUD operations in less than one minute, but if I have to omit a operation, in this case, delete, do I have to create one by one my method? or how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude or include specific routes using the `routes` property of the @Crud decorator. `exclude` allows you to list routes that will *not* be provided, while `only` lets you declare which routes *will* be provided.

You could use the following to specifically exclude the Delete route:

```
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: User
  },
  routes: {
    exclude: ['deleteOneBase'],
  }
```

See the [nestjsx/crud routes](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#routes) section of the wiki for additional `routes` properties.

The @Crud decorator gives you lots of control over your routes. In addition to `routes`, you'll find the `params` and `query` properties to be incredibly useful.